# Устройство подключенное по витой паре к компьютеру "отваливается"

Tags: wifi, маршрутизатор, tp-link

У меня есть TP-Link CPE 220 я его проверял он работает, но когда я подключил его по витой паре (40м длинна) ПК видит его, через секунду нет и так все время, он отваливается.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Плохой кабель или все таки он очень длинный для данного роутера

Comment: 40 метров - не длина, даже для китайского алюминиевого кабеля. Проверяйте целостность кабеля, качество обжима коннекторов (особенно внимательно). Если точка доступа стоит на улице, то возможно попадание воды, окисление контактов разъема RJ-45

Comment: Возьмите ноутбук, подойдите к устройству поближе и проверьте на другом, коротком кабеле. Так Вы выясните виноват ли кабель.

Comment: Кабель плохой оказался, заменил все заработало